# Does SQLite Connection needs to remain open(connected) to take advantage of Pragma Cache_size?

Tags: c#, database, caching, sqlite

I've always thought that the best practice to manage database connections is to connect to it, perform a query and immediately close the database connection

However, as for SQlite, I stumbled across their website the following snippet with regards to PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE
From the [SQlite Website](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size)

> PRAGMA cache_size;  PRAGMA cache_size = pages;  PRAGMA cache_size =
>   -kibibytes;
>
> Query or change the suggested maximum number of database disk pages
>   that SQLite will hold in memory at once per open database file.
>   Whether or not this suggestion is honored is at the discretion of the
>   Application Defined Page Cache. The default page cache that is built
>   into SQLite honors the request, however alternative
>   application-defined page cache implementations may choose to interpret
>   the suggested cache size in different ways or to ignore it all
>   together. The default suggested cache size is 2000 pages.
>
> If the argument N is positive then the suggested cache size is set to
>   N. If the argument N is negative, then the number of cache pages is
>   adjusted to use approximately N*1024 bytes of memory. Backwards
>   compatibility note: The behavior of cache_size with a negative N was
>   different in SQLite versions prior to 3.7.10. In version 3.7.9 and
>   earlier, the number of pages in the cache was set to the absolute
>   value of N.
>
> When you change the cache size using the cache_size pragma, the change
>   only endures for the current session. The cache size reverts to the
>   default value when the database is closed and reopened.

Doe this means that for me to benefit from Memory Caching, I need to remain connected to the SQLite Database File througout the duration of my appllication? The moment I disconnect the database, all cached memory is lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is indeed dropped when closing the connection.

Both in SQLite and in all other databases, opening a connection has some overhead.
Using many short-lived connections is *never* a good idea.

In situations where you do have many independent, short-lived pieces of work (such as a web server), you typically work around these inefficiencies by using connection pooling.

Comment: Thanks, but why do everyone say frequent opening and closing is always better?

Comment: Because "everyone" is stupid? (This is not a question on-topic on SO …)